# Player icon auto generator

Tags: java, avatar

Hi I am searching for an open library (preferred in java) to generate user icons / badges for representing an user in an mmpg, rather than by his player name. The user does not need to take any actions to manipulate the icon by him self, but the system is auto generating the icon when the user is registering. Is there any library / script out there to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: There is a nifty system in OpenTTD, which generates random faces, by gluing together hair, eyes, skin color, and some other features. These features can be changed by the user.

Answer (score 6):

If abstract icons are fine, you could somewhat use [gravatar](http://gravatar.com).

If you want to have human-like icons instead, not allowing the user to customize them is a bad bad bad idea.

Another option is to use facebook login and use player's avatar.

Comment: Gravatar is unfortunatly not an option, since I am not asking for the users email address and it is not nice, because it uses the real identity of an user, but it should be a fictional identification.